# probably something wrong in ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I'm new to JS/AJAX/PHP and i'm trying to make the simplest login page:

**HTML and JS/AJAX**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function login() {
            if ($("#username").val() === "" && $("#psw").val() === ""){
                alert("Username and Password required")
            }else{
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "login.php",
                    data: "username=" + $("#username").val() + "&password=" + $("#psw").val(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        if (responseText === 0){
                            alert("x");
                        }else if (responseText === 1){
                            alert("y");
                        }else{
                            alert("z");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    </script>
 </head>
<body>
     <form id="form">
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Login</legend>
            <strong>Username</strong>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="min. 5 characters" />
            <strong>Password</strong>
            <input type="password" name="psw" id="psw" placeholder="min. 8 characters" />
            <br>
             <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" onclick="login()" />
         </fieldset>
     </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**PHP**

```
     <?php
 if (isset($_REQUEST['username'])) {
     $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
     $password = $_REQUEST['password'];

     $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
     $db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "login_esercizio");

     $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";
     $data = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
     $row = mysqli_num_rows($data);

     if ($row <= 0){
         echo 0;
     }else{
         echo 1;
    }
 }
```

As you can see it's a simple AJAX call.
I tried to understand why this code is not working, but i can't figure it out.
MySQL is working and PhpStorm have interpreter, everything is fine.
I made a select to see if there is data inside MySQL, and there is it.

I think there's something wrong in AJAX call, but i can't figure it out because i can't know/see the problem.

Tell me if i have to be more clearer, i'm pretty new here, also sorry for my english.

Comment: look in the dev console on your browser, specifically the js console and the network tab

Comment: I would also try a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` to see if the parameters you're sending are getting through. But I'd second the dev console to see if the request is actually being made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that when you click the `submit` button to execute the AJAX request you're also submitting the `form`. As the form has no `action`, this cancels the AJAX request and refreshes the page.

To do what you require you need to stop the form submission by hooking to the `submit` event of the form and calling `preventDefault()`. You can also improve the logic by using unobtrusive event handlers in JS code, instead of the outdated `on*` event attributes.

Note that `responseText` will be a string, so you need to compare the values with that data type. It would even be more reliable to return JSON to avoid issues with whitespace when returning text, but the below should at least work for you:

```
$(function() {
  $('#form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop form submission

    if ($("#username").val() === "" && $("#psw").val() === "") {
      alert("Username and Password required")
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "login.php",
        data: {
          username: $("#username").val(),
          password: $("#psw").val()
        },
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (responseText) {
          if (responseText.trim() === '0'){
            alert("x");
          } else if (responseText.trim() === '1') {
            alert("y");
          } else {
            alert("z");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <h1>Login Page</h1>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Login</legend>

    <strong>Username</strong>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="min. 5 characters" />

    <strong>Password</strong>
    <input type="password" name="psw" id="psw" placeholder="min. 8 characters" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rory McCrossan! This answer is perfect, it opened my eyes on how AJAX works and how to work with HTML.